# Utility Bar Not Showing Lightning Dialer

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, softphone

I just purchased, enabled, and activated the utility tab for Lightning Dialer in my production org. I made sure the profile has access and there are 1 inbound and 1 outbound license available to be used.

The utility tab isn't showing the phone section on the standard Sales app (I made sure to edit it and make sure dialer was on the utility tab) nor is it showing up when I create a new app and enable it on the utility tab.

Is it not possible to enable this directly in production? I followed the trailhead step by step so I have to assume it is either taking some time to install or it can't be directly deployed. Has anyone else run into this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the users assigned to a call center and have the right permissions? It wont show up if they cant use it.

Comment: you are right, the user did have the inbound and outbound dialer permission set assigned. It is working now!